# How to deal with messy numeric data in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I'm creating a tibble using dplyr but having issues because some of the columns are numeric except for one or two exceptions:

Something like this:

```
> tibble(station = c("Sapporo", "Kushiro", "Hakodate", "Akita", "Rumoi", "Hokkaido East"), pulse_width = c(1, 1, 1, 1, "0.67, 1.0, 1.33", "100-300"))
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  station       pulse_width    
  <chr>         <chr>          
1 Sapporo       1              
2 Kushiro       1              
3 Hakodate      1              
4 Akita         1              
5 Rumoi         0.67, 1.0, 1.33
6 Hokkaido East 100-300
```

Where most of the values for pulse width are just numbers but there are a few with multiple values or a range.

Right now I just convert columns like this to chr but is there a better way to handle this?

Edit: The table is of different radar systems. I think it would mainly be printed in a paper and used to get values for an interactive map, so a lot of the values like pulse_width just need to be displayed in a way that people can read. But ideally I would also be able to do stuff like sort those columns.

Comment: the best solution depends what you are going to be doing with the table and what those non-numeric values actually mean.  Can you give more information?

Comment: what should the output of the sample above look like?

Comment: You can use `tidyr::separate_rows` to make three rows out of `0.67, 1.0, 1.33`. However, you have mixed data types in your column, because `100-300` might be an interval and not a single number point. For this I would make a new column `pulse_width_range`

Answer (score 0):

You should mention whats the desired output. Good that you hinted that you want to sort these so a numerical / character column is needed. (Preferably numeric)

I would try different approaches for such data.

1. Check the unique values in the data. If there are not many, just map them with some case_when() etc to a new column
2. for non-numerics (10-30 or 0.67,1,3) : Ask for the logic to covert them into a number. Users can guide on that. Apply that logic. :-)
3. as suggested by danlooo : Create columns to handle similar data types (after split/modifying) and then combine the results later. In soem use cases, I have to do that to treat with care such "special data"

my 2 cents.
Since I cannot post a comment, hope this is not downvoted/deleted as an "Unacceptable answer".